# Output a dataframe consisting of columns by for loop

Tags: pandas

I have 3 csv files, each of single columns.
I tried to read them by for loops and output a single dataframe (DF)

```
files = ['a.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.csv']

index = np.arange(np.datetime64('2010-01-01'), np.datetime64('2010-01-11'))
columns = list(map(str,range(len(files))))

DF = pd.DataFrame(index=indices, columns=columns)
print (DF)

for i, f in enumerate(files):
  raw = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=',')
  raw = raw.set_index('Dates').reindex(index).reset_index()
  DF[str(i)] =raw
```

but no success, any ideas?

edit:

the file contains this kind of data:

a

```
1/1/2010    5
1/2/2010    6
1/3/2010    7
1/4/2010    9
1/5/2010    1
1/6/2010    39
1/7/2010    5
1/8/2010    32
1/9/2010    1
1/10/2010   1
1/11/2010   0
```

b

```
1/1/2010    5
1/2/2010    19
1/3/2010    7
1/4/2010    9
1/5/2010    1
1/6/2010    24
1/7/2010    5
1/8/2010    32


c 

1/1/2010    34
1/2/2010    27
1/3/2010    34
1/4/2010    21
1/5/2010    34
1/6/2010    34
```

Comment: can you explain ix from where ?

Comment: sorry, it is i.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pd.concat`

```
files = ['a.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.csv']

index = np.arange(np.datetime64('2010-01-01'), np.datetime64('2010-05-31'))
columns = list(map(str,range(len(files))))

s=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=',').set_index(0) for f in files],axis = 1)

s=s.reindex(index).reset_index()
s.columns=columns
```

Update

```
DF = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

for i, f in enumerate(files):
  raw = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=',')
  raw = raw.set_index(0).reindex(index).reset_index()
  DF[str(i)] =raw
```

Comment: @hiker change the set_index(0)

Comment: could you modify using the for loop as in my question, because difficult to understand yours...

Comment: nope,   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '0'

Comment: @hiker that should be set_index(0)

Comment: again,   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

Comment: also, print (DF) is all NaN though, set_index('Dates') corrected previous error.

Comment: I think, there is problem in DF[str(i)] =raw